# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - protecting the production env from accidental deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for some advice on best practices managing an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application.

I have an app with 2 different environments which I refer to as `prod` and `dev`. I would like to allow deployments to the `dev` env to all collaborators and limit deployment to `prod` to only one user.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElasticBeanstalk tightly integrates with IAM.

Allowing or Denying a user a specific action on a specific resource can be achieved by attaching the correct policy to the role being assumed.

[The ElasticBeanstalk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html) have a specific section explaining IAM permissions in EB, and the last example on the page is effectively what you’re looking for. Modify the policy shown to your needs and attach it to the users or groups of users you wish to deny access to the production environment.

Your policy is going to look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteApplication"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateConfigurationTemplate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteApplicationVersion",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteConfigurationTemplate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteEnvironmentConfiguration",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplicationVersions",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationSettings",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentResources",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
        "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteEnvironmentConfiguration",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RebuildEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RestartAppServer",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
        "elasticbeanstalk:SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs",
        "elasticbeanstalk:TerminateEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplicationVersion",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateConfigurationTemplate",
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
        "elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:123456789012:environment/Test/Test-env-prod"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above policy is going to prevent any user with this policy attached from Creating or Deleting any applications, and it's further going to deny the user from completing any of the listed actions on the resource ARN listed; the app named `Test` and the environment named `Test-env-prod`.

To restrict access to the specific environment you could use this policy and modify the ARN's `region` (us-east-1), `account-number` (123456789012), `app-name` (Test), and `environment-name` (Test-env-prod), to your specific needs.

You can find a list of ElasticBeanstalk resource ARN formats [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.arn.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've encountered this doc, I'm looking for a way to limit access to a specific env, but the page only explains access limitation to the application level. Do you know of a way to limit access to an env within an application or should I just create a different application with a dev environment?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  You simply need to apply the correct ARN to the resource in the policy.  I've given an example ARN format that I tested; if you modify it to have your apps production environment ARN the user will not have access to any of those actions on that environment; if they're looking in the console they won't even see it.